# I don't know how to update an entry by it's unique id

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

[![This is how the DB looks like
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfGPP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfGPP.png)[image]I have this app that gets an item from the firebase real time  DB and displays it nicely but I am not able to edit the item via the app :(

I mean I need somehow to get the unique ID generated when inserting an item ..

For the display part I use `Object.entries(data).map((item, index) => (item.key = index));`

Comment: When you insert an item , you can use getKey() to get the parent key of that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html#key

1. Get the whole object with the key

```
let retrievedItem;
const items = firebase.database().ref(itemsPath);
items.once('value').then(
  snapshot => snapshot.forEach(item => {
    retrievedItem = {id: item.key, ...item.val()};
  })
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#update

2. Update the item

```
items.child(retreivedItem.id).update(updatedObject);
```

Comment: Ok, I tried the first one and I don't get de ID ..  I get like ```name: "", date: "15-05-2019", type: "ITP", imageURI: "https://playtech.ro/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/ITP-Masina-control-reguli-ani-1170x658.jpg```

Comment: could you post a minimal reproduction of your project with the issue either on github or stackblitz?

Comment: Sure, https://github.com/alexalghisi/TestApp/pull/7/files#diff-2ada015b41b77e07f3ea42e4e14234a6

Comment: But here I did not add ```items.once('value').then(
  snapshot => snapshot.forEach(item => {
    retrievedItem = {id: item.key, ...item.val()};
  })
```

Comment: well, you don't get the id, because you just return ```snapshot.val()```. And that object contains your items, but ids are not attached to them when you return ithem that way. That's why you have to loop through the snapshot, and create a new object from every item in that snapshot: ```{ id: item.key, ...item.val() }```.

Comment: I still don't get it how .. it got too complicated with Firebase :(. How should I change items.once('value') to get both value and id ??

Comment: Do it like this

```items.once('value').then(snapshot => snapshot.forEach(item => {
  const newObj = {id: item.key, ...item.val()}; 
}))```. That's it. 


```newObj``` contains both the id of the item and its value.